# 12V-to5V (3A) converter for car fuse box

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

I'm planning to setup a RetroPi (using Raspberry Pi 3) in my car with a direct connection to the fuse box with this 12V-to-5V (3A) converter module. The power requirements on the Raspberry calls for 5.25V. Is this going to not work or possibly damage the board?

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MEESLZ6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o08_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MEESLZ6)

Thanks.

Comment: Be cautious of the large voltage drop/spike when starting your car. Going direct to the fuse box/battery will help with that, but there could still be an issue. Is the pi going to be running all the time? There will also be some draw on the battery even if the pi is not running. Probably not enough to worry about assuming you start/drive the car regularly.

Answer (score 1):

That voltage converter should work fine.

The Pi requires 5V +/- 0.25V (because that's the USB standard, and the default power supply is via a microUSB socket).